# Not able to parse string to date in logstash/elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-4

I had created a logstash script to read a logfile which is having various timestamp of format "2018-05-08T12:18:53.506+0530". I am trying to parse it to date using the date filter in log stash

```
date{
     match => ["edrTimestamp","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'","ISO8601"]
     target => "edrTimestamp"
}
```

The running the above logstash script it creates a elastic search index. But still the string is not parsed to date. It is also showing date parsed exception in the index.

It creates output like this.

```
{
          "tags": [
            "_dateparsefailure"
          ],
          "statusCode": "805",
          "campaignRedemptionLimitTotal": 1000,
          "edrTimestamp": "2018-05-22T16:41:25.162+0530 ",
          "msisdn": "+919066231327",
          "timestamp": "2018-05-22T16:41:25.122+0530",
          "redempKeyword": "print1",
          "campaignId": "C910101-1527004962-1582",
          "category": "RedeemRequestReceived"
        }
```

Please tell me whats wrong in the above code> I had tried many others alternative but still it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your timestamp has a space at the end of it `"edrTimestamp": "2018-05-22T16:41:25.162+0530 ",` which is causing the date parsing to fail.  You need to add a:

```
mutate {
  strip => "edrTimestamp"
}
```

before your date filter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be escaping the Z. So you probably want something like:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS
```

Also you should not be using "Z" since your time is not Zulu (0 offset). You will want to contain the offset as part of the pattern. The [Heroku grok debug app](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)  is useful for this.

If I pass your string

```
2018-05-08T12:18:53.506+0530
```

and use the filter `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}` then it matches, this pattern is made up of the following sub-patterns:

```
 TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?
```